# grep double quoted string along with simple string from file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression

Below is the output of

```
pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start > /tmp/startup.log
```

command to check if service is already running.

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
```

Above is the string/message we get from `startup.log` file if services is already running.

The `" "` is ignored when `grep`ing the string and so I am not able to fetch the exact string. I want to grep above string from `FATAL` to `exists` as it is.

Below is the code which I trying.

```bash
if grep -q 'FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists' /tmp/startup.log; 
then
     echo "$host postgreSQL instance is  already running "
fi
```

Comment: show us your actual grep command, this question is unanswerable without it because we can't see what you're doing wrong.    but as a general tip: escape double-quotes with backslashes, or modify the pattern to avoid needing to do that (e.g. `grep '^FATAL:.*lock file.*exists$'`)

Comment: What is the content of `$PGDATA`. Is the _actual_ string `"postmaster.pid"` relevant, or only that there is a string enclosed in double-quotes?

Comment: @cas, added more info.    $PGDATA means (/pg/data)

Comment: Why are you inspecting `/tmp/pg_startup.log` when you wrote to `/tmp/startup.log`?

Comment: Cannot confirm. For me it works fine, the `"` are working fine. However, you should use `grep -F` when using a fixed string, or better check Kusa's answer and evaluate `pg_ctl` return value.

Comment: I'm noticing that you have asked a number of questions by now, but that you haven't accepted _any_ of the answers that you have received. Consider accepting the most helpful answers to each question (if they have helped you solve the issue).  Doing so will mark the issue as resolved, and it will also increase your chances of getting help in the future. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pg_ctl` directly to test whether the startup of the database was successful, but only if you use it with its `-w` option.  This option waits for the startup to complete before giving control back to the calling shell.  Without `-w` you can't really know when it's ok to check that the database system is up and running.

```bsh
export PGDATA
if ! pg_ctl -w start >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo 'Failed to start database' >&2
fi
```

The `PGDATA` variable will automatically be used if it is an environment variable.  Would you want the server to do logging, then use `-l /path/to/logfile` with `pg_ctl`.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. but i have multiple condition .. so i tried and resolved. I will put ans for same. grep is not working if the strings have single/double quotes.

Comment: @AdamMulla You should describe your multiple conditions in your question.  Grep does not have an issue with quotes in the pattern.